# Best way to handle a real-time clock?

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I'm building an application for a linux platform in C, with a GTK+2 GUI. I need to keep a real-time clock running on the screen displaying HH:MM:SS (only needs to be accurate to the second), and then have various functions triggered at specific times entered by the user in a GTK_ENTRY field.

I've been researching the best way to do this, and have found similar questions where people have answered to use GThread threading to monitor the time, but I have not been able to find any specifics.

Can I send a function that contains an endless loop, constantly checking the time over and over, to a thread? Somehow that doesn't seem right, or the best way to handle it.

I would really appreciate any specifics anyone can offer, or any direction towards resources that might answer this question.

Thank you!

Comment: You should be aware that timers like this are widely frowned upon as one of the reasons most modern Linux software is not suitable for low-power devices like tablets...

Comment: Coming from a mostly objective-c and iOS background, I certainly understand what you're saying, and that this is not the most elegant and efficient way of doing things. But this project is for a very specific embedded touch-screen panel device, in a very specific setting. This means my hands are somewhat tied in regards to options, but also means that I don't really need to worry about it being used in a universal sense. However, if anybody has a more elegant solution to recommend, I'm completely open to suggestions.

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense. I just wanted to caution you about putting unneeded timers in general-purpose apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a glib timeout handler, using `g_timeout_add()`. If you use a period of, say, half a second you should be fine. In the handler code, do whatever widget manipulation is needed in order to refresh the displayed time. This might be as simple as formatting some text for a GtkLabel.

Of course, I don't recommend that you use the "ticking" of the timeout callbacks as the actual clock source, you should use regular API:s to find out what time it is in each callback.

Comment: This definitely seems like what I'm looking for, and is a lot easier than dealing with threads! I will try it out this afternoon. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to read the documentation about those functions.  Those are based on the monotonic clock, not the real time clock. http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#g-get-monotonic-time

Comment: @Fred: That shouldn't matter as long as OP follows the advice to call `clock_gettime` or similar and not try to maintain the time based on counting timer events.

Comment: I think I understand. I had already written my function that updates the display to the current time once, using GDateTime objects and g_date_time_new_now_local() and it works fine. I was just stuck getting that function to repeat over and over at least once per second. Is the monotonic clock trustworthy enough for that level of accuracy?

Comment: I'd suggest [`g_timeout_add_seconds`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) , or [`g_timeout_add_seconds_full`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds-full) if you need to tweak the priorities.